# slider that also magnifies around cursor

Tags: javascript, user-interface, slider

It can be difficult to use (webpage) sliders that cover a large range with fine granularity. On the one hand, it is easy to move across the range. On the other hand, it is difficult to locate the exact point one wants, assuming a fine enough granularity.

I was thinking that a magnify effect around the cursor could solve this problem (assuming the problem really exists).

I looked for existing solutions or ideas via google, but couldn't find anything.

Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if this is what you're looking for, but... within Mac OSX, holding down the control key and moving the scroll wheel will zoom in and out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble thinking of a scenario where having so much data that scrolling of this nature would be a problem you'd want to have.  In almost all scenarios it makes more sense to chunk up the data or reduce it down in some other way.

About the only thing that makes sense is the seek-bar/scrubber on a video player.  If your player is 400px wide with a 360px wide scrubber, but the video is an hour long, the best granularity you'll get is 10 seconds-per-step (with the step-size being 1 pixel).

If that isn't enough granularity, then it's possible you'll need to augment your scrubber with another UI convention - which *could be* a magnifier - but it could also be other things.  Like a "jump to point" text field that would allow to user to entire a time and seek to that exact position.

Comment: video is a great example. just trying to find the right location, even at 10 sec intervals, can be challenging. why not make the "move to 4:10" just as zippy as moving to the end of the scroll bar?

Comment: Yeah, but a zoom would be clunky.  Why not implement a separate controls that's like a radial dial?  The skee-bar for moving quickly through the data, and the dial for fine-tuned adjustment.

Comment: i guess i assumed automatic magnify (think Mac dock) would be less clunky than two controls, but it's worth trying both. the advantage of two controls is that those widgets already exist :-)

i've seen log-scale sliders, btw. that's pretty neat in the case where the desired granularity changes with the data points.

Comment: Yeah, but auto-magnify means you then *lose* the speed of zipping around w/the non-magnified seeker.  I have serious reservations about how easy an "always-on" magnifier would be to use, anyway.  I'm not saying don't use a magnifier, I think you just stop trying to force this all into a single UI control.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're going for something (visually) like the OS X dock. This is called a fish-eye effect. There's a jQuery plugin for a [fish eye menu](http://blog.jquery.com/2007/05/09/fisheye-dock-menu/) which you may be able adapt and merge with a slider to give you the functionality that you're looking for.